# How can I bring a window to top and simulate a click on it?

Tags: delphi, click, simulate

I am running a Delphi application multiple times and I need to bring each one to top and simulate a mouse click somewhere on its form.

In my app I have a TWebBrowser component and I want to click somewhere in that browser. The thing is that I need to click on flash object inside that browser. I tried to get the ClassName and Handle to click on flash, but is not working with all websites. So the only thing that works is to simulate a mouse click.

For example I load this link into the browser http://bit.ly/XWaelU and I am trying to simulate click on the big "play" button from the flash player inside.

Can someone help me with an example code on how this can be done?
I think the application must be launched with fixed position so the coordinates of the click remain the same, right?

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by _simulate a mouse click_, for example, you want to push a button or what are you trying to accomplish? 
Do you want to do this from inside the application or from an external app?

Comment: In my app I have a TWebBrowser component and I want to click somewhere in that browser. The thing is that I need to click on flash object inside that browser. I tried to get the ClassName and Handle to click on flash, but is not working with all websites. So the only thing that works is to simulate a mouse click.

Comment: you better edit and add that vital info to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to click a control on the window, with known position relative to the window, from which you have (can get) the handle, you could use this. Demo only on the current form.
Maybe adapted to your conditions.

```
Procedure SetWindowTopAndClickOnRelPos(wnd:HWND;Pos:TPoint);
var
  ChildControlHandle:HWND;
begin
  SetForegroundWindow(wnd);
  ChildControlHandle:=  ChildWindowFromPoint(WND,pos);
  SendMessage(ChildControlHandle,WM_LButtonDown,0,5*$FFFF + 5);
  SendMessage(ChildControlHandle,WM_LButtonUp,0,5*$FFFF + 5);
  Form4.Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('ChildControlHandle: %d',[ChildControlHandle]));
end;

procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Window: %d',[Handle]));
     Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Button: %d',[button2.Handle]));
     SetWindowTopAndClickOnRelPos(handle,Point(Button2.Left + 2,Button2.Top + 2));
end;

procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Showmessage('Hallo');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I edited my question to be more specific what I want.